# React Native FBSDK ShareDialog return isCancelled true on successful post

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I would like to know if anyone experienced the same issue. The code is just this.

```
ShareDialog.canShow(shareLinkContent).then((canShow) => {
     if (canShow) {
          return ShareDialog.show(shareLinkContent);
      }
}).then((result) => {
      console.log(result)  // this thing right here is a problem
});
```

The issue only happens in release mode/build specifically iOS only . . Normally if user successfully posted a link the return is an empty object `{}` while if cancelled it will return `{isCancelled: true}`. Right now in iOS test flight or even the exported ipa everything returns `{isCancelled: true}` even if you successfully share the link on facebook.

"react-native": "0.61.2"

"react-native-fbsdk-next": "4.3.0",

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I reverted back to `react-native-fbsdk@3.0.0` to make it work . . Not sure what is the difference between `react-native-fbsdk` and `react-native-fbsdk-nex`t but I am not experiencing this issue on `react-native-fbsdk`.

Case closed